# Не запускается хост

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Почему-то перестал запускаться хост.

Если раньше в консоли писалось, что все ОК и хостится по определенному IP, то сейчас ничего не пишется, а методы API недоступны.

В тоже время никаких исключений не вылетает. Единственное, что я в последнее время меня- это пароль от учетки. По идее, если бы чего-то не хватало, то должен был происходить вылет по таймауту. Куда копать?

```
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .CaptureStartupErrors(false)
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseHttpSys(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.Schemes =
                    AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://*:20019");
                options.MaxRequestBodySize = config.GetValue<long?>("maxRequestBodySize");

            })
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
        var initializer = host.Services.GetService<IRepositoryInitializer>();
        initializer.Init();
        host.Run();
```

Возможно, это важно, но точка останова в методе `Configure` не срабатывает=> почему-то этот метод не вызывается...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, просидел где-то час со включенным приложением и в консоли выскочило сообщение, что все было инициализировано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что удивительно, после этого все последующие запуски стали проходить моментально.

Не знаю, что это было... Может быть в каком-то месте аутентификация медленно проходила...